# Add multiple logo to presentation with CambridgeUS

Tags: beamer, logos

I am preparing a presentation in `beamer` with `CambridgeUS`theme. 
With regard to affiliation logos, I know that I can add one with titlegraphics as `\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{My_Logo}}` , but I want to add a second logo and I tried a again `\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{My_Logo2}}` with no success.

So my questions:

1. How can I add multiple logos in title page?
2. How can I include these logos to the templeta at the bottom?

Comment: It is probably easier to format your own title page than modify \maketitle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      % european characters
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}  % use mathematical symbols
%\usepackage{mwe} % helps 1st time use to  load example images
\usepackage{palatino}         % use palatino as the default font
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-A}} % It matters not where this line goes the content is placed at bottom of frame
\title[Short Title]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-duck}\newline Deuxième Cours} % We can embed an image in the title
%\subtitle{02  L'Entree:- Canard citron} % some things are best not said and we have to lose some lines somewhere
\author[M.W.E.]{\small Author: M'r Exemple\newline % Removing this newline or beter still \Author (combine with institute) would improve spacing a lot
Assistant: exemple de travail minimales}
\institute[]{\footnotesize Dept de \LaTeX, Uni de la Vie.} % Condense into one line to gain more space as the date will be automatically added next
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage 
\end{frame}
Bonjour Monde 2
\end{document}
```